# Create a table using definition list and grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Here is my attempt to create pseudo-table, using `<dl>` and `display: grid`.

Actually, it works. The only problem, is that I forced to use ugly way to define rows. It is completely manual way. So if I have 30 rows in table, it will be really very dumb to repeat `dt + dd + ... + dd` for each of them.

How this issue could be fixed?

(I don't want to use real tables, because it is for Markdown).

```css
dl {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

dt {
    text-align: center;
}

dd {
    margin-left: 0;
}

dt, dd {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    padding: 0 1em;
}

/* Ugly part
 * (Red, yellow, and green colors are just for demo)
 */

dt {
    grid-row-start: 1;
}

dt + dd {
    grid-row-start: 2;
    color: rgb(244, 67, 54);
}

dt + dd + dd {
    grid-row-start: 3;
    color: rgb(255, 152, 0);
}

dt + dd + dd + dd {
    grid-row-start: 4;
    color: rgb(76, 175, 80);
}
```

```html
<dl>
    <dt><p>Term 1</p></dt>
    <dd>
        <p>Definition of term 1 long long long long</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </dd>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 1</p></dd>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 1</p></dd>

    <dt><p>Term 2</p></dt>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 2</p></dd>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 2</p></dd>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 2</p></dd>

    <dt><p>Term 3</p></dt>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 3</p></dd>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 3</p></dd>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 3</p></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: If it's a table, why aren't you using `<table>`?

Comment: @Rob Because it is for Markdown. That way, I could use multiline tables in Markdown. It works.

Comment: I have a feeling you shouldn't be using markdown for this.

Comment: I have feeling you just don't understand my task. I write documents in Markdown. My parser could read definition lists, so I can create them easily. And now, with that fix, I could also create multiline tables.

Comment: Definition list (and their lack of wrapper around dt+dd) and grid layout: nice idea! edit: for their common layout

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming... you're on Firefox or Chrome but not IE/Edge :p, here's a working solution with any number of terms and any number of definitions for each term:

➡️ **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/YVdboG?editors=0100)**

Explanations:

1. filling the grid column after column ➡️ `grid-auto-flow: column;`
2. (grid items) each term should be on row 1, so its definitions are below it  ➡️ `dt { grid-row-start: 1 }` acts like *"next column please"*
3. Create enough explicit rows (say, 50) but the row N+1 should show (have any height) only if any given term has at least N definitions (4 rows visible if the max definitions for a given term is 3. None has 4) ➡️ `grid-template-rows: repeat(50, min-content);`
4. Then tried to have an undefined number of columns/terms but I couldn't achieve it with explicit columns (I wanted something like *"1fr if there's content but 0 otherwise"* with minmax(), min|max-content to no avail). Worked like a charm with implicit columns though: ➡️ `grid-auto-columns: 1fr;`

```css
dl {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    /* doesn't assume 3 terms but N */
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(50, min-content); /* doesn't assume 3 defs but M<50 */
}

dt {
    grid-row-start: 1; /* reset, next column */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting, works :) Probably I will accept it a bit later, in several days. Currently I want to wait a bit, to make this question more visible on the tracker. Maybe someone else have different ideas about how to fix it... It's a bit bad that we must specify number of rows (`50`). But it is still big improvement over my original.

Comment: I would be surprised if a better answer is posible. Let's wait, any way.

Comment: `50` isn't really specifying a number; it's more like an unrealistic one imho :) I didn't want to write 500 or 1000 in case browsers'd start using too much memory or CPU cycles or whatever as long as it isn't needed.

Answer (score 3):

Based largely on FelipeAls answer, but simpler and without need for an artificial number of rows.

Just change grid-auto-flow to row, and things become easier.

```css
dl {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
}

dt {
    grid-row: 1;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

dt, dd {
    border: solid 1px silver;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
    <dl>
        <dt><p>Term 1</p></dt>
        <dd>
            <p>A Definition of term 1 long long long long Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non inventore impedit cum necessitatibus corporis, ratione culpa nesciunt corrupti recusandae voluptate, sint magni enim ullam quo, ipsum. Voluptatibus quos aliquid, optio!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </dd>
        <dd><p>B Definition of term 1</p></dd>
        <dd><p>C Definition of term 1</p></dd>
        <dd>May the 4th</dd>

        <dt><p>Term 2</p></dt>
        <dd><p>A Definition of term 2</p></dd>
        <dd><p>B Definition of term 2</p></dd>
        <dd><p>C Definition of term 2</p></dd>

        <dt><p>Term 3</p></dt>
        <dd><p>A Definition of term 3</p></dd>
        <dd><p>B Definition of term 3</p></dd>
        <dd><p>C Definition of term 3</p></dd>
    </dl>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it is simpler and now there is no need to specify a number of rows. It's a good news! But, for justice, I should note that this method is much less tolerant to any "errors" in table, in comparison with original FelipeAls version. Here is examples: [FelipeAls](https://jsfiddle.net/chrry7qm/) version and [yours](https://jsfiddle.net/msuxr4kd/).

Comment: Yes, I agree. (I already commented it in his answer) The only reason for posting this answer was to provide an example without the artificial row number. But I would choose his answer for production code.

Comment: Each `dd`efinition is related to the last `dt`erm found in markup. Here they're displayed from left to right (then top to bottom err I mean rows are filled one after another) thus the 2nd definition of the 1st term (B1) is displayed in the column of the 2nd term when it should be displayed in the 1st column (that's why I added those A B C in my answer)

Answer (score 2):

One alternative (cross-browser) approach is to give the parental definition list relative positioning:

```
dl {position: relative;}
```

and then give every sub-element inside the definition list an absolute position.

```
dt, dd {display: block; position: absolute;}
```

*(Naturally, since we're now using absolute positioning, this is only going to be a viable alternative if you have a good idea about what the maximum width of each data column and maximum height of each data row ought to be).*

In this instance you will still have to give an explicit `left` value for each `dt` and `dd`, but the declaration is identical each time apart from the index (referenced three times) which increments like so...

**Example:**

```
Index 2: dt:nth-of-type(2), dt:nth-of-type(2) ~ dd {left: calc((1px + 1em + 200px + 1em + 1px) * (2 - 1));}
Index 3: dt:nth-of-type(3), dt:nth-of-type(3) ~ dd {left: calc((1px + 1em + 200px + 1em + 1px) * (3 - 1));}
Index 4: dt:nth-of-type(4), dt:nth-of-type(4) ~ dd {left: calc((1px + 1em + 200px + 1em + 1px) * (4 - 1));}
```

etc.

**Working Example:**

```css
dl {
position: relative;
}

dt {
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
}

dt, dd {
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
min-height: 50px;
margin-left: 0;
border: 1px solid lightgray;
padding: 0 1em;
vertical-align: top;
}

dt {
top: 0;
}

dd:nth-of-type(3n - 2) {
top: 50px;
height: 200px;
color: rgb(244, 67, 54);
}

dd:nth-of-type(3n - 1){
top: 250px;
color: rgb(255, 152, 0);
}

dd:nth-of-type(3n) {
top: 300px;
color: rgb(76, 175, 80);
}

/* LEFT CO-ORDINATES */

dt:nth-of-type(2), dt:nth-of-type(2) ~ dd {
left: calc((1px + 1em + 200px + 1em + 1px) * (2 - 1));
}

dt:nth-of-type(3), dt:nth-of-type(3) ~ dd {
left: calc((1px + 1em + 200px + 1em + 1px) * (3 - 1));
}
```

```html
<dl>
    <dt><p>Term 1</p></dt>
    <dd>
        <p>Definition of term 1 long long long long</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </dd>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 1</p></dd>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 1</p></dd>

    <dt><p>Term 2</p></dt>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 2</p></dd>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 2</p></dd>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 2</p></dd>

    <dt><p>Term 3</p></dt>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 3</p></dd>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 3</p></dd>
    <dd><p>Definition of term 3</p></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Looks a bit similar to my alternative version, which wasn't showed in original post. Here it is, if you wondering: https://jsfiddle.net/pdqem653/ :)